# How to publish to the web a Google spreadsheet without gridlines?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to publish my sheet to web but i don't want to see the gridlines. I have tried to hide gridlines in my sheet. But the gridlines is still visible when i publish to web.

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridlines should automatically be hidden in the published copy when you hide them in the spreadsheet. Try reloading the window where you are viewing the published copy.

Comment: Thanks, I found out it's not refreshing right away, even after manually re-start publishing (stop and then start publish). I need couple of reload to be able to see it updated.